# 【RubyMine】Debugger does not start

Tags: ruby, rubymine

### Overview

I am developing using RubyMine.

I wanted to use RubyMine's debugging function as excellent, I got an error.

### Detail

Add a break point
↓
Debug button pressed
↓
console

```
/bin/zsh -c "bash -c 'env RBENV_VERSION=2.7.1 /Users/katahira/.rbenv/libexec/rbenv exec ruby /Users/katahira/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-2.3.0/bin/rdebug-ide --key-value --step-over-in-blocks --disable-int-handler --evaluation-timeout 10 --evaluation-control --time-limit 100 --memory-limit 0 --rubymine-protocol-extensions --port 53995 --host 0.0.0.0 --dispatcher-port 53996 -- /Users/katahira/dev/work/〇〇.rb'"
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 2.3.0, debase 2.3.0, file filtering is supported, block breakpoints supported, smart steps supported, obtaining return values supported, partial obtaining of instance variables supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:53995
Uncaught exception: uninitialized constant Api
    /Users/katahira/dev/work/〇〇.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### Tried

- Check version

```
katahira@MBP 〇〇 % rbenv versions
  system
  2.4.1
  2.5.8
  2.6.3
  2.6.5
  2.7.0
* 2.7.1 (set by /Users/katahira/dev/work/〇〇/.ruby-version)←current directory
  2.7.2
  3.0.0
```

RubyMine → preferences → Ruby SDK Gem
rbenv: 2.7.1
[image]

- Check gem
  RubyMine → Preferences → Ruby SDK Gem → rbenv:2.7.1

```
ruby-debug-ide 2.3.0
・
・
・
debase 
  debase 2.3.0
  debase
```

[image]

[image]

### Environment

OS macOS BigSur
ruby 2.7.1 (2.6.5 is described in the gemfile)
rails 6.0.4('~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.7' is described in the gemfile)
docker Baseimage FROM ruby:2.6.5-alpine

Comment: Which RubyMine version are you using? Does running the script fail with the same error?

Comment: Thanks. RubyMine 2020.2.4
Build #RM-202.8194.9, built on November 25, 2020

Comment: Install the lastest version(2021.1), press debugger button, it will automatically install the debugger gem debase and ruby-debug-ide and it will start to run. But your problem seems to be you are having someother problem from your program, just check whether you are using the constant api. Ruby Mine debugger perfectly works for me. I have been using more than 5 years now.